# Drop Pandas dataframe rows if geocoordinates outside country shapefile

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda, data-science

I'm working on a script that will filter and drop any rows containing coordinates outside a specific country shapefile.

Here's what I have so far

```
import pandas as pd
import shapefile
from shapely.geometry import Point 
from shapely.geometry import shape 

df = pd.read_stata(r'C:PathtoDataFrame')
shp = shapefile.Reader(r'C:PathtoShapeFile') 
all_shapes = shp.shapes() 
all_records = shp.records()    

def InCountry(lo,la):
    point_to_check = (lo, la) 
    for i in range(len(all_shapes)):
        boundary = all_shapes[i] 
        if Point(point_to_check).within(shape(boundary)):
            #Inside country shape file
            return (1)
        else:
            #Outside country shape file
            #return (0) this doesn't work use pass instead   
            pass

#Create copy of dataframe with only incountry coordinates
df_copy = df.apply(InCountry(df.geopointlongitude, df.geopointlatitude))
```

However, I keep getting a

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> error
```

When I run the script.

1. How can I solve this?
2. How can get the InCountry function properly filter the geocoordinates.

Any suggestions on how to improve the script are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the TypeError, try replacing the code for creation of dataframe copy as follows:

```
df_copy = df.apply(lambda x: InCountry(x.geopointlongitude, x.geopointlatitude), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks this removes the error, however, the `InCountry` function always returns 0, whether the coordinate is in the shape file or not, any suggestions?

Comment: Replacing `return (0) ` with `pass` worked for me, I've updated the question